# UPI deep linking from Ionic3 is not working on Android

Tags: android, ionic3, cross-platform, payment, upi

I am using this:

> options=
> { action:this.webIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
> url:"upi://pay?pa=xxx@upi&pn=Name&tid=TID4587445785&tr=Product
> Purchase&am=100&cu=INR&tn=Purchase&mc=< my mc code >" };
>
> this.webIntent.startActivityForResult(options)

However, it's failing with these errors:

**Google Pay Error** `limit exceed`

**paytm Error** `payee-mcc length invalid`

**Bhim Error** `Payee.code numeric of length 4`

Could not figure out a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone from stackoverflow masterminds? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I got the solution. Anyway thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: can you share your solution

Comment: @saikrupa, I just create a Paytm Business account and scan the qr code for their marchent upi ID and use it in my own upi payment link. That's all. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rajib ,

Give Merchant code as only of 4 digit .. Thats the one that is causing issue

Comment: I solved that already. Merchant code will not help because each and every UPI apps have different merchant code and criteria. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

create your uri as below :

```
val paymentUri = Uri.Builder().apply {
        with(payment) {
            scheme("upi").authority("pay")
            appendQueryParameter("pa", vpa)
            appendQueryParameter("pn", name)
            appendQueryParameter("tid", txnId)
            appendQueryParameter("mc", merchantId)
            appendQueryParameter("tr", txnRefId)
            appendQueryParameter("tn", description)
            appendQueryParameter("am", amount)
            appendQueryParameter("cu", currency)
            appendQueryParameter("mcc", payeeMerchantCode)
        }
    }.build()

    // Set Data Intent
    val paymentIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        data = paymentUri

    }
val appChooser = Intent.createChooser(paymentIntent, "Pay using")
if (paymentIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(appChooser, PAYMENT_REQUEST)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "No UPI app found! Please Install to Proceed!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        throwOnAppNotFound()
    }
```

Here mc or merchantId has to be 4 digit and payeeMerchantCode you will get when your account on these psps